# Laravel: 1060 Duplicate column name while running migrations

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I am getting the following error when running migrations:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate
>   column name 'role_id'")

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        if(!Schema::hasTable('users')) {
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('middle_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('role_id');
         });
    }
}
```

I have deleted most of the migrated tables as it gives duplication issues. Could that be related to my existing problem ?

Comment: did you deleted this migration before you ran it?

Comment: why you are not running new migration file for editing the user table

Comment: seems to be you already have the table in your database, or you have already run the migration.

Comment: Better if you could post DB structure

Comment: that means you already added that column

Comment: Do you use Laratrust in your project?

Answer (score 2):

try running these commands in your terminal:

1. `composer dump-autoload // updates whatever you changed in your migration`
2. `php artisan migrate:fresh // migrates migration from the start`

if these doesn't not work, post your column structure so we can understand more about your problem.

Comment: it did not work. Now the user table is empty and i cannot loggin. Update: i have again registered as a user and the login works now.

Comment: Now the current situation is like before all the migrations were created. But Those all old tables exists in the editor. If i have to create all migrations fresh, it will be a waste of time for me. Could you advise me whether i could use all the existing migrations in the editor.

Comment: Somehow Migrations worked now without error. I didnt had to create all those old migrations from the scratch fortunately.

Comment: if you have a seeder,  then use this command `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`.